# How to crop the contoured portions (more than 1) from the image and pick a horizontal section for color histogram

Tags: python, opencv, contour

How to crop the contoured portions (more than 1) from the image and pick a horizontal section for color histogram

Comment: Get the bounding boxes of each contour (x,y,w,h). Then use numpy slicing to crop them. `crop = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]` See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html.

Comment: I have done this now. :)

Comment: @fmw42 - How can I pick a horizontal line (I don't want to draw a line, as it will need to have a color, which will destroy the color of the original image) from the cropped area to get the color of it?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question.